# how to 3-way outer product in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

About the numpy.outer [[link]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) .

Given two vectors, `a = [a0, a1, ..., aM]` and `b = [b0, b1, ..., bN]`, the outer product will be M*N matrix.

1. But how to implement a 3-array outer product, which means : given
   third vector `c = [c0, c1, ..., cP]`, how to get the outer product
   between the 3 numpy arrays.
2. and how to get n-way outer product for n-array in numpy, for the method of `einsum`, how to change `'i,j,k->ijk'`  to process `"n"` .

Answer (score 11):

The direct way of doing this, taking full advantage of broadcasting is:

```
a[:,None,None] * b[None,:,None] * c[None,None,:]
```

`np.ix_` does this reshaping for you, at a modest cost in speed

```
In [919]: np.ix_(a,b,c)
Out[919]: 
(array([[[0]],

        [[1]],

        [[2]],

        [[3]],

        [[4]]]), array([[[10],
         [11],
         [12],
         [13]]]), array([[[20, 21, 22]]]))
```

and the resulting arrays can be multiplied with

```
np.prod(np.ix_(a,b,c))
```

The `einsum` version is simple, and fast

```
np.einsum('i,j,k',a,b,c)
```

It's a good idea to learn all 3 methods.

The problem with nesting `outer` is that expects the inputs to be 1d, or it flattens them.  It can be used, but needs some reshaping

```
np.outer(a,np.outer(b,c)).reshape(a.shape[0],b.shape[0],c.shape[0])
```

Comment: `np.prod(np.ix_(a,b,c))` returns `ValueError ... The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape` as of Python 3.10.9 and Numpy 1.24.2. Using `math.prod` instead of `np.prod` works.

Comment: @GiancarloSportelli, that's because `np.prod` is first making an array from the tuple, and new numpy versions have tighten up that process.  `np.prod(np.array((a,b,c)). dtype=object))` should run ok.  The change was in the `np.array...` step, not the `np.prod`.  `math.prod` works because it iterates on the tuple directly.  Both do a repeated product, `(A*B) * C`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `numpy.ix_`; it adds axes to its operands such that they form an open grid. Below the shapes of A,B,C are `(2, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1)` and `(1, 1, 4)`, so just multiplying them together results in the outer product.

```
a = np.arange(1, 3)
b = np.arange(1, 4)
c = np.arange(1, 5)
A,B,C = np.ix_(a,b,c)
A*B*C
# array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
#         [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
#         [ 3,  6,  9, 12]],
#
#        [[ 2,  4,  6,  8],
#         [ 4,  8, 12, 16],
#         [ 6, 12, 18, 24]]])
```

Comment: Could use `np.prod(np.ix_(a,b,c))` to remove the `A,B,C` assignment.

Comment: True. Will leave it as is, though, for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

You could [use `einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for this:

```
>>> numpy.einsum('i,j,k->ijk', [1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6,7,8,9])
array([[[18, 21, 24, 27],
        [24, 28, 32, 36],
        [30, 35, 40, 45]],

       [[36, 42, 48, 54],
        [48, 56, 64, 72],
        [60, 70, 80, 90]]])
```

---

You cannot cross arbitrary amount of vectors using `einsum`. The indices can only be letters, so [at most 52 vectors are allowed in this form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794245/can-i-use-more-than-26-letters-in-numpy-einsum/37796451) (although [it will raise "too many operands" when 32 vectors are provided](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ab9b15ef0a80ea002d12498554853544bb25ad57/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L2515)):

```
def nary_outer_einsum_52(*vectors):
    import string
    subscripts = string.ascii_letters[:len(vectors)]
    subscripts = ','.join(subscripts) + '->' + subscripts
    # expands to `numpy.einsum('a,b,c,d,e->abcde', v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4])`
    return numpy.einsum(subscripts, *vectors)
```

einsum supports another form which uses numeric indices instead of letters, which unfortunately [only support up to 26 vectors](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7741) because it just translates to the letter version internally. I **do not** recommend using this until the bug I mentioned is fixed.

```
def nary_outer_einsum_26(*vectors):
    operations = (x for i, v in enumerate(vectors) for x in (v, [i]))
    # expands to `numpy.einsum(v[0], [0], v[1], [1], v[2], [2], v[3], [3], v[4], [4])`
    return numpy.einsum(*operations)
```

`numpy.ix_` ([@PaulPanzer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43148960/224671)) can easily be scaled up to the N-ary case. Still, there is an implementation-limit of 32 vectors:

```
def nary_outer_ix(*vectors):
    return numpy.prod(numpy.ix_(*vectors), axis=0)
```

---

timeit with 3 vectors:

```
>>> timeit.Timer('nary_outer_einsum_52([1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9])', globals=globals()).autorange()
(100000, 0.8991979530110257)   # 9 µs / iteration
>>> timeit.Timer('nary_outer_einsum_26([1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9])', globals=globals()).autorange()
(100000, 1.0089023629989242)   # 10 µs / iteration
>>> timeit.Timer('nary_outer_ix([1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9])', globals=globals()).autorange()
(10000, 0.30978472300921567)   # 31 µs / iteration
```

with 26 vectors:

```
>>> timeit.Timer('nary_outer_einsum_52(*([[1]] * 26))', globals=globals()).autorange()
(10000, 0.6589978060073918)   # 66 µs / iteration
>>> timeit.Timer('nary_outer_einsum_26(*([[1]] * 26))', globals=globals()).autorange()
(10000, 0.7502327310066903)   # 75 µs / iteration
>>> timeit.Timer('nary_outer_ix(*([[1]] * 26))', globals=globals()).autorange()
(1000, 0.2026848039968172)    # 203 µs / iteration
```

with 33 vectors:

```
>>> nary_outer_einsum_52(*([[1]] * 33))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in nary_outer_einsum_52
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/einsumfunc.py", line 948, in einsum
    return c_einsum(*operands, **kwargs)
ValueError: too many operands
>>> nary_outer_ix(*([[1]] * 33))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in nary_outer_ix
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py", line 83, in ix_
    new = new.reshape((1,)*k + (new.size,) + (1,)*(nd-k-1))
ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32
```

Comment: Not much summing going on in that particular `einsum` ;-) Still, it is much faster than mine.

Comment: Thanks, but how to do  when the "n" arrays outer product?

Comment: @AliceSmith this `np.einsum(*[arg for pair in zip(a_list, np.arange(len(a_list))[:, None].tolist()) for arg in pair])` should work. Sorry, it's a bit clunky.

Comment: @AliceSmith See update. Practically you can't support n > 32 though.